# Jenkins - Is there any way to run a subproject if parent project fails?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins, I have two projects that run builds on two separate slaves.  If the build fails on a slave, then the corresponding Jenkins project fails--this is intentional.  If a build succeeds on a slave, then the corresponding Jenkins project succeeds, and any subproject of that Jenkins project executes.  This is normal and expected by Jenkins design, according to my knowledge.

If both projects succeed, I want to insert a " SUCCESS" tag in Mercurial source control.  If one of the jenkins projects fail, then I want to insert a " FAIL" tag in Mercurial source control.  What I was thinking is having a jenkins project execute when one or both of these fail.

I know how to implement the success aspect of my design.  However, is there a way to execute a project iff a parent project fails?

Is this possible in Jenkins?  If so, how?

(don't worry about the Mercurial details...those aren't important...I was just trying to explain that I want to tag success if both projects succeed and tag fail if even one of the projects fails.

Comment: Using a comment because I have zero experience with Jenkins (Outside of Pals for Life consultanting :) ) - but I'd use a number variable to accumulate successes. numberOfPasses = 0; each time a project passes, numberOfPasses++, then if numberOfPasses == 2, write the success tag, else write the fail tag. Good luck!

Comment: When you refer to "parent project" and "subproject", are you maybe talking about a multi-configuration job, also sometimes known as matrix job? And if you are not, could you clarify what is a subproject and parent project for you?